# how to add custom Keras model in OpenCv in python

Tags: python, opencv, keras

i have created a model for classification of two types of shoes

now how to deploy it in OpenCv (videoObject detection)??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

You can do that with the help of OpenCV DNN module:

```
import cv2

# Load a model imported from Tensorflow
tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow('card_graph/frozen_inference_graph.pb', 'exported_pbtxt/output.pbtxt')

# Input image
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
rows, cols, channels = img.shape

# Use the given image as input, which needs to be blob(s).
tensorflowNet.setInput(cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))

# Runs a forward pass to compute the net output
networkOutput = tensorflowNet.forward()

# Loop on the outputs
for detection in networkOutput[0,0]:

    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.9:

        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows

        #draw a red rectangle around detected objects
        cv2.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (0, 0, 255), thickness=2)

# Show the image with a rectagle surrounding the detected objects 
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

you need frozen inference graph and pbtxt file to run your model in OpenCV

Comment: thanks for your help!! , suppose that my model name is `detection.h5` so now how can i deploy it here??

Comment: Its pretty straight forward convert your .h5 model to .pb format then you can use it. You cannot directly use .h5 model in OpenCV

Comment: when i put `detection.h5` in `tensorflowNet = cv2.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow()` this happened ` kernel appears to have died.`

Comment: and what is my atLast concern is , after applying this custom model into OpenCv , i have few images which is having a 5 types of shoes , that's why i want to apply my custom model  , so i want to draw rectangle on those two  shoes  only (that thing you have done, thanks for that)

Comment: Yes as I said "You cannot directly use .h5 model in OpenCV". You need to convert it into a .pb file first

Comment: In order to avoid long thread of discussion If you need further assistance please contact me through the email on my homepage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196630/discussion-between-jony-and-ajinkya).

Answer (score 0):

You would save the model to H5 file model.save("modelname.h5") , then load it in OpenCV code load_model("modelname.h5"). Then in a loop detect the objects you find via model.predict(ImageROI)